# Bash reverse search inserting characters into command after hitting tab

Tags: bash, command, string, search

**SYSTEM:**

- Ubuntu: 20.04
- Kernel: 5.4.0-162-generic
- bash: 5.0.17(1)

I found a strange problem that when I use bash's reverse search with CTRL+r, I will find a command I want to run. I select TAB to select it before running, and for some reason bash will insert a string into the command.

Like if the command I want to use is this

```
(reverse-i-search)`sele': docker exec -it my-postgres psql -P pager=off -P expanded=auto -U database -c "select * from stuff;"
```

After I hit tab what is presented to me is this

```
docker exec -it my-postgres psql -P pager=off -P expanded=auto -U database -c "my-select * from stuff;"
```

see how `my-` is inserted in front of `select`? I tried cleaning up my history with -d and writing with -w. But still this behavior continues. It only happens for speific history commands through. So if I did `echo dog` and reverse searched it, pressed tab, then `my-` is not inserted.
I also tried searching for other words in the command like `pager`, or `auto`, and the behavior still happens.
On a last note I did try searching for the first word `docker`, if I hit TAB then, this behavior does not insert `my-`. Seems to be fine for the first word.

Does anyone know why? I don't do anything crazy with `.bashrc` here is the only things I added at the end

```
# User specific aliases and functions
set -o vi
alias lc='stat -c "%A %a %h %U %G %n" * | column -t'
alias vi=vim
export PATH=/home/fsnt/bin:$PATH
export EDITOR='vim'
export VISUAL='vim'
```

Here is my `.inputrc`

```
#vi mode adding TextObject Motions
$if mode=vi
set keymap vi-command
"ciw": "lbcw"
"yiw": "lbyw"
"ciW": "lBcW"
"yiW": "lByW"
$endif
```

Comment: Don't use tab to select the command. Use esc or Ctrl-J (by default). Tab does completion. (This is true in emacs mode, vi mode may differ).

Comment: I cant use Ctrl-J. I use that key binding for something else. Is there a way I can use a different key binding? Also where can I find documentation on using bash reverse search? I found this (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html) But it doesn't mention using TAB or what it does actually.

Comment: That still leaves Escape. You can list the current bindings with `bind -p`. You can also use a movement key to select the command during search, e.g. I often use `C-e` (go to end of line) to accept the search as I may want to add something at the end of line.